# Importing EV fields with MPXJ returns null values

Tags: mpxj

I'm using MPXJ to import EV fields from MS Project 2007. When importing .mpp file, all EV fields returned null. I then saved the file in XML formt... now I get only ACWP, the remaining fields are still null.
Of course, I'm sure that the file has actual EVM values, I can seem them in MS Project.

Can you please help? Thank you in advance.
Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't been able to locate the various Earned Value fields in the MPP file. I suspect that MS Project may be calculating these values dynamically, hence I can't read them using MPXJ. In future I may be able to add Earned Value calculation to MPXJ.. but that's probably a long way off!